# Normal vector of an implicit curve

Tags: real-analysis

We consider the equation $y^2-4y+4+x^2y+\arctan(x)=0$, the exercice of my book say that the normal vector $n$ of the cartesian curve implicitally defined by the previous equation is $n=l(1,0)$ for $l \neq 0$. I don't understand the reason of this affermation, because I think that if $y(x)$ is the implicit function obtained form the equation, the parametric equation of the curve is $(t, y(t))$, so the first coordinate of the normal vector is zero.
I would therefore expect that the normal vector is $n=l(0,1)$. Is it right?

Comment: Is it possible that they are asking for the point where the normal is $(1,0)$?

Comment: From the reasoning of Hallsoflvy, I think yes, I think that they are asking for the point $(2,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x,y)=x^2 y+\arctan x+y^2-4 y+4=0\tag{1}$$
The points where the normal is parallel to $(1,0)$ are those where the tangent is vertical.

This happens when looking for intersection with a vertical line $x=k$ the equation gives a double root.Plug $x=k$ into equation $(1)$

$$k^2 y+\arctan k+y^2-4 y+4=0$$
discriminant is zero when
$$k^4-8 k^2-4 \arctan k=0$$
which gives $4$ values  for $x$ as can be seen in the image below

$$x=0,x=-2.71,x=-0.48,x=2.93$$

Points are $$(0,2),(-2.71,-1.67),(-0.48,1.89),(2.93,-2.29)$$

[image]

Comment: Very helpfull thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's a little odd.  The tangent vectors and normal vectors to a **curve** typically vary in direction but the result you give doesn't!  IF the normal vector is always in the direction (1, 0) the tangent vector is always in direction (0, 1) (or (0, -1)) so is a straight line of the form x= constant.

The curve is given by $y^2- 4y+ 4+ x^2y+ a tan(x)= 0$. The derivative is given by $2yy'- 4y'+ 2xy+ x^2y'+ a sec^2(x)= 0$.
$(2y- 4+ x^2)y'= -2xy- asec^2(x)$

The slope of the tangent line at point $(x_0, y_0)$ is $-\frac{2x_0y_0+ a sec^2(x_0)}{2y_0- 4+ x_0^2}$ and the slope of the normal line at that point is $\frac{2y_0- 4+ x_0^2}{2x_0y_0+ a sec^2(x_0)}$.  The normal line at that point is given by $y= \frac{2y_0- 4+ x_0^2}{2x_0y_0+ a sec^2(x_0)}(x- x_0)+ y_0$

Comment: Thank you, from your reasoning I think that the exercise asks for the point (0,2)